# database and a new c# windows form appI used a datagridview and joined it to access data base

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

I have created a new access database and a new c# windows form app.
I used a datagridview and joined it to access data base.
Now when i change into database it show in gridview but when u change in grid view it would not be save despite i have checked the edit delete and add but they wont be saved in database  I mean when u close the program and open it again the changes haven't been saved.